# file_put_content save in several files, limit by rows

Tags: php, foreach, limit

Instead of saving all the lines in 1 file (using file_put_content), I want to save several files, each file contains a certain number of rows.
As file1.txt file2.txt

i have this code:

```
$file = foreach($rows as $row) {
  $row['domain']
}

file_put_contents("file.txt", $file, LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
<?php
$i=1;
foreach($rows as $row) {
  file_put_contents('file' . $i . '.txt', $row['domain'], LOCK_EX);
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: how can i defind number rows on file like that?

Comment: how can i do it with a for?